# The mbstring extension is missing?

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, wamp

I know there's tons of topics about my problem, but I can't find a solution.

I'm using wamp and I've changed my version of  PHP from 5.5.12 to 5.6.16, then when I go to localhost/phpmyadmin i have this error displayed :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in
>   C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on
>   line 177

So I update phpMyAdmin from 4.1.14 to 4.5.2.

And I have this **** error:

> phpMyAdmin - Error The mbstring extension is missing. Please check
>   your PHP configuration.

My php.ini, phpForApache.ini is configured, I have un-commented the extension, set extension_dir to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.16\ext, I stumbled on many topics/forum but none of the solution works.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: you need to manually add the extension *and then relaunch PHP*, I had this updating to 5.6 as well. Use `phpinfo(8)` to show you which extensions your current build has loaded.

Comment: Have you actually restarted Apache? That seems to be what you're missing, from your question.

Comment: I restarted wamp, and apache services,   doesn't work. mbstring doesn't appear in phpinfo(8)

Comment: Then have you named the extension directory correctly? The problem is that PHP is not able to find the extension so check things like using the correct slashes and/or using the correct drive designator (I don't know if your WAMP php would use something other than `C:`, etc. Are you sure the files are in the specified folder? Do you need a trailing slash on the pathname?

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976764/why-cant-php-on-windows-see-extension-php-intl-dll-even-though-it-exists

Comment: ahhh, thanks Martin, it works ! thanks for your time !

Comment: What was the solution, what was the cause of the issue? This is useful for future readers of the post to read

Answer (score 5):

Please check [#36254548](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599406/phpmyadmin-mbstring-error/36254548)

Copying the php.ini file to "wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin" has solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the extensions directory is well pointed to, the dll files have been uncommented but it still doesn't work.

The next solution to use, that is if your extensions directory is correct and dll files for the mbstring has been uncommented, then copy the php.ini file and paste it into the windows directory (i.e. C:\Windows).

You then restart your wamp/xampp and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

check your php.ini file. In the extensions part of the configuration you should find:

```
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

remove the leading ';' to uncomment and enable the extension so it looks like this:

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

restart your apache and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I start wamp, suddenly my project was not working and when I check the phpmyadmin, it gives the same above error.

My debugging process found php.ini file is missing. However I already installed two PHP versions, 5.6.19 and 7.0.4. I changed the version to 7.0.4 and then re-changed to 5.6.19. It started work.

What I guess, while changing the version, all the configuration files getting re-installed in wamp folder.