# php_intl.dll loading, The specified module could not be found issue. XAMPP on windows

Tags: php, xampp, apache2, cakephp-3.0, intl

I am using 
XAMPP :- v 5.6.31 (3.2.1)
    apache :- 2.4.26
    PHP    :- 5.6.31
OS :- Windows 10

When I was trying to run my CakePHP project on xampp server, I got an error "***Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\config\bootstrap.php on line 23***", so I search the internet I got the solution that I have to enable the php_intl extension so I have enabled it by uncommenting the line of code from the php.ini .

After that when I tried to restart my apache I got an error, "***PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found***."

I have searched for the resolution but nothing seems to work in my case. Could you please guide me to solve my issue.

I have gone through this links for guidance and no answer solved my problem.

[To enable intl extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl)

[To get rid of loading issue of php_intl.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976764/why-cant-php-on-windows-see-extension-php-intl-dll-even-though-it-exists)

[image]

Comment: Try copying all the `icu*.dll` files from the PHP folder to the `apache\bin\` folder

Comment: I tried but didn't work for me :( @RiggsFolly

Comment: Does `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll` even exist on your system?

Comment: Yes that exist and I am also copied this to apache\bin folder. @GregSchmidt