# XAMPP Error PHP intl not loading “Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found”

Tags: php, xampp

I am running XAMPP on Windows Server 2016, the error I am running into is as follows:
Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

I’d like to note that this error began when I moved XAMPP over from my VPS to my dedicated server.

I have been unable to resolve this issue with the guidance of the other questions posted here. Any assistance is sincerely appreciated.

Still looking for assistance on this issue, any help is appreciated. I think it is duly noted that this all started once I moved my XAMPP over from my VPS to my dedicated server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [intl extension: installing php\_intl.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't PHP on Windows see extension php\_intl.dll even though it exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976764/why-cant-php-on-windows-see-extension-php-intl-dll-even-though-it-exists)

Answer (score 0):

Check if [extension_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dirrw) is e Rapointing to correct directory. Also, add extension=php_intl.dll directive. This will solve the problem.

Eyv v5,*z and eyv TGVhinuyku*
    Wr6:55¥ 
Hi Y vt

> ryu a cvyyy
>   Block quote

Comment: The extension_dir points to the correct place and the extension=php_intl.dll is already there and is not commented. I am still having the issue.